# why does my functor member variable "reset" ? (c++)

Tags: c++, functor

I am Learning how to use functors, and so i created one, and i don't understand why my counter variable is 0 at the end of the programm.

here the code:

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<map>
#include<list>


using namespace std;

class myFunctor {
public:
    myFunctor():counter(0) {}
    void operator()(int i) { cout << "in the functor: " << i ; counter++; cout << "   counter=" << counter << endl; }
    int getCounter() const { return counter; }
private:
    int counter;
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    myFunctor f;

    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), f);

    cout << "counter=" << f.getCounter() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what the result gives:

```
in the functor: 1   counter=1
in the functor: 2   counter=2
in the functor: 3   counter=3
in the functor: 4   counter=4
in the functor: 5   counter=5
in the functor: 6   counter=6
in the functor: 7   counter=7
in the functor: 8   counter=8
in the functor: 9   counter=9
in the functor: 10   counter=10
counter=0
```

Comment: You never actualy modify anything but temporary copies, so why would you expect anything else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a look at the signature for `for_each` you will see that it accepts the functor by value, so the changes you see inside `for_each` are not reflected outside when the algorithm terminates.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction >
UnaryFunction for_each( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f );
```

---

If you want to make this work you are going to have to use `std::ref` to generate a reference wrapper and pass that by value.

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ref(functor));
```

Take a look at the [documentation for `std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) and `reference_wrapper` to see how and why this works (the key point is that `std::reference_wrapper` has an `operator()` to work with functors http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator()).

Comment: Or, alternatively, capture the return value of `for_each`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the signature of for each:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

It copies the functor f, so the original is untouched.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer of Curious is the best solution, here is another one:

```
class myFunctor {
public:
    myFunctor():counter(std::make_shared<int>(0)) {}
    void operator()(int i) { cout << "in the functor: " << i ; ++*counter; cout << "   counter=" << *counter << endl; }
    int getCounter() const { return *counter; }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> counter;
};
```